# Which programs use the new "Online Accounts"?

Tags: 11.10, settings, google, online-accounts

In Ubuntu Oneiric 11.10 it's possible to configure a Google Online Account. I'm able to configure this program to get access to Mail, Contacts, Calendar and Chat.

But which programs use this data? There is no information about that.

After I configured my Google Account, I supposed that I will be able to use Google Chat with Empathy, or that I will be able to access my Contacts and Calendar in Thunderbird.

But none of this is true. So, how does Ubuntu use the configured Google Accounts?

Comment: this is how ubuntu **should** be using the account setup. If its not working then it is a bug which you should add to launchpad

Comment: Related (identical?): http://askubuntu.com/questions/63891/how-to-integrate-gnome-online-accounts

Comment: @Bernd - If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 6):

The idea is that those types of accounts should be configured in one place and then all other programs can get your identities. Your email clients, IM clients, VoIP, photo albums, etc.

Obviously, any tool must exist before applications can start to use it, so it's no surprise that many applications doesn't use this yet. I thought at least Empathy would use this now, though?

Answer (score 5):

**gnome-contacts** uses **Google Contacts** if you set up an online account.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-contacts
```

or click [this](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-contacts)[image: Install Gnome Contacts]

Answer (score 3):

According to [the Gnome 3.2 release notes](http://library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.2/#goa).

**Online Accounts**

Documents, contacts, calendars — They can be stored locally on the computer, but storing this type of information online is becoming increasingly popular. In GNOME 3.2, Online Accounts provides one place to manage these online sources. These online accounts are automatically used by Documents, Contacts, Empathy, Evolution as well as the calendar drop-down.

Probably this features didn't make it to unity yet.