# How do I synchronize Thunderbird with Google Contacts

Tags: evolution, 11.10, thunderbird, google

At the moment I'm testing Ubuntu Onieric. I always used Evolution as my email client, but now I would give Thunderbird a chance.

But I couldn't find a way to synchronize my Google Contacts with Thunderbird. What is the preferred way in Ubuntu to do this?

1. The Add-on don't work with Thunderbird 7: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/google-contacts/
2. Thunderbird EDS Contacts integration isn't available in the repos: https://launchpad.net/thunderbird-eds-extension
3. the new Online Account settings doesn't have any impact here: [Which programs use the new "Online Accounts"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60077/which-programs-uses-the-new-online-accounts)

So what's the right way to synchronize my Google Contacts information with Thunderbird on Ubuntu Onieric 11.10?

Answer (score 6):

Go to http://www.zindus.com/ or https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/zindus/ it works at least with thunderbird 7 alpha 1 and it's the add-on I use

Comment: Zindus add-on works perfectly for me too. Good answer.

Comment: Sadly the add-on don't work with the lastest Ubuntu Onieric installation.
"Zindus could not be installed because it is not compatible with Thunderbird 7.0"

Comment: I'm using Zindus with Thunderbird 7.0.1 on Oneiric. It's a great piece of software.