# How to integrate gnome-online-accounts?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, online-accounts

There is a new feature called gnome-online-accounts, which has been introduced in Gnome3 , but its still not integrated into Ubuntu 11.10.
Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: I read somewhere that Gnome online accounts give access to your online data via API calls. For example, one can access Google Docs from one's Google account. It would be nice if something like Libre Office Writer can allow me to access and edit Google Docs! But I have not seen any application using this as yet...

Comment: I can see events from my Google Calendar in Unity datetime-indicator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been looking at this from the perspective of adding support for this in some GNOME Do plugins.  `gnome-online-accounts` is basically a single-sign-on API.  It provides a way for applications to get an authentication cookie for the configured online accounts.  It does not provide anything else; it's up to the application to know how to use that cookie to talk to the online service.

As such, it's entirely dependent on the applications to (a) query `gnome-online-accounts` for configured online services, and (b) actually know how to interact with those online services.

You can think of it as basically `gnome-keyring` for your online services.  It has been integrated into Ubuntu 11.10, in so much as the GNOME apps which support `g-o-a` will use it; there just aren't many apps that use it yet ☺.

Comment: This is how it's supposed to be http://library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.2/#goa How it is in 11.10 right now is obviously not as it's supposed to be :-/

Comment: What?  Barring the GTK theme, that is _exactly_ how it looks on my Oneiric system.

Comment: Hello all. I have added the online services in the system settings. However, my question is how to get the services working. My calendar does not show dates from google calendar and empathy does not pick up my gmail account for chat. Evolution does not pickup my gmail account for emails. I have to add them manually.

Answer (score 3):

It seems its partially incorporated! I installed gnome-documents. It works. It picked up the documents from my google docs after a restart. However Evolution and Empathy does not pickup gmail and gtalk automatically. It has to be added manually. It does not show events from google calendar as well.
UPDATE: After today's update, Evolution is automatically picking up gmail accounts and google calendar dates are being shown below the calendar in both Unity and Gnome SHell. Only updates missing are from Empathy. I am assuming this will be integrated by 13th.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but it looks like basic support was integrated into ubuntu 11.10 recently. After updating, you can find it in the user indicator under 'Online Accounts...'

Answer (score 0):

The online accounts only work with Google at the moment. According to a post on the Gnome developers mailing list we should see more coming down the line, but possibly not until Gnome 3.4 [list thread](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2011-April/msg00107.html)

Of course I am assuming that once this gets developed Ubuntu will have it integrated as well.