# What are online accounts and how do they work?

Tags: online-accounts

While playing around with my 11.10 install I found a section under the "MeMenu?" which was labeled "Online Accounts"

[image]

What is this feature and how does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Online accounts is one of the latest features of GNOME 3.2.

The [release notes of GNOME 3.2](http://library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.2/#goa) states:

> **Online Accounts**
>
> Documents, contacts, calendars — They can be stored
> locally on the computer, but storing this type of information online
> is becoming increasingly popular. In GNOME 3.2, Online Accounts
> provides one place to manage these online sources. These online
> accounts are automatically used by Documents, Contacts, Empathy,
> Evolution as well as the calendar drop-down.

Useful links:

1. [How to integrate gnome-online-accounts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63891/how-to-integrate-gnome-online-accounts)
2. [GNOME 3.2 Release Notes](http://library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.2/#goa)